# Did I understand the derivatives equation wrong for this question?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I was taught that for a function $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ can be found by doing  $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.

In one of my questions I am given the function $R(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2sin(x),  & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

It asks me to show that $R'(0)=0$. However when I use the derivative equation I have $R'(0) =$ $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(0+h) - (0)}{h}$ $=$ $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{h}$ $=$ $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} 1$ $=$ $1$.

Did I understand the derivatives equation wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you think that $R(h)=h$? By the definition you wrote, $$R(h)=h^2\,\sin h.$$